# RouteHandler attr value has three preceding dots

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am going through a react-router code from [here](https://github.com/akiran/reddit-clone/blob/master/client/js/app.jsx#L19). This is a simpler implementation of reddit posts website.

`RouteHandler` takes an extra attribute as `{...this.state}`.

```
          <div className='content'>
            <RouteHandler {...this.state} />
          </div>
```

What does triple dots inside curly braces mean?

`this.state` is not explicitly assigned a value, what does it get resolved as?

And how does this pick up one of the three route handlers defined in the `routes` variable [here](https://github.com/akiran/reddit-clone/blob/master/client/js/app.jsx#L29) -

Comment: https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/07bbe37bc42b6d4aef81

Comment: @limelights: "flower brackets" --- that made my day :-D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [ES6 spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), what it does is that it unpacks an array into individual parameters that gets sent into the RouteHandler.

While this only works for arrays in ES6, the JSX transformer will allow you to use this syntax for objects as well enabling you to use it on objects such as `this.state`.

Updated to clarify thanks to @zerkms;

Comment: From the link you've pasted: "The ... operator (or spread operator) is already supported for arrays in ES6. We're also pushing to get the spread operator for object properties in ES7."

Comment: That's right. There is a spread operator **for arrays** in ES6. There is **no** spread operator **for objects** in ES6.

Comment: I still don't like it much, but at least it's not that misleading now ;-)